# Trying to find a way to display from 2 tables and 4 rows and display per today and order of start time

Tags: sql, html-table, rows

I have an Booking calendar for rooms, MySQL driven. I would like to read data from 2 tables - and from each 2 rows:

- Table `entry`:

  ```
  id
  start_time
  End_time
  entry_type
  repeat_id
  room_id
  timestamp
  creat_by
  name
  ```
- Table `room`:

  ```
  id
  disabled
  area_id
  room_name
  sort_key
  ```

Ideally I want to read the columns `start_time`, `room_id` and `name` from table `entry`. As well as the `room_name` from table `room`.

I am still dreaming so now I would like to have these grouped by corresponding and written out in html table grouped as name in one line/table and the three others in a table one the line below

```
         room name| start time |-|end_time|
```

I have been trying with this but can't seem to get it to do what I am dreaming about.

```
 if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
       FROM  $bookings
       WHERE start_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) 
       AND   start_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
       ORDER BY start_time, room_id");

if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body></html>
```

Please help

Comment: Thanks nikola, I think I understand a little bit morebutwhen I try it I only get unexpected T_Variable in the first line of the query:// sending query
$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM $bookings.start_time, $bookings.name, $rooms.room_name 
FROM $bookings 
   inner join $rooms 
      on $bookings.RoomID = $rooms.RoomID 
WHERE start_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)  
AND start_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
ORDER BY start_time, room_id);
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about php, but I think that the query should look like this:

```
SELECT start_time, bookings.name, rooms.room_name
FROM bookings
   inner join rooms
      on bookings.RoomID = rooms.RoomID
WHERE start_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) 
AND start_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
ORDER BY start_time, room_id
```